# what is the use case $ComponentLabel

Tags: global-variables

The documentation is not very clear.

[Click here for SF documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_componentlabel.htm)

Answer (score 3):

As the official Doc says:

> Return the label of an inputField component that is associated with a Message.

This applies to Message instances which are associated with specific components in the page - namely `<apex:inputField />` elements. The global variable allows you to retrieve the field label in a generic manner when the Message is associated to a specific field.

Apex [Message Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_message.htm#apex_ApexPages_Message_ctor) documentation which relates to this scenario.

---

*Example*:

You need to show the error messages of a DML operation on your VF. The validation rules and triggers will fill the messages collection setting the error message related to each field which has a problem.

Then, on your VF you could list the messages using a datalist and show the label of the fields that have errors along with the message text.

```
<apex:datalist var="mess" value="{!messages}">
  <apex:outputText value="{!mess.componentLabel}:" style="color:red"/>
  <apex:outputText value="{!mess.detail}" style="color:black" />
</apex:datalist>
```

Will show you:

- **Amount** can not be lower than 100.
- **Close Date** can not be empty.

Comment: Thanks for reply , but I am confused , what a datalist retruning here. List of string and why we are not user $ sign if its a global varible and Serially I am not able to understand the use case. If datalist is case list of wrapper class then componentLable must a property of this wrapper class. Actually SF did not specified the apex code here and making confusing like me people.